# Compute aggregate on insert and update rather than on select

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MS Sql Server 2016, I have a view that contains a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, MAX(Col3) FROM TableA 
WHERE Col1 = ???
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

I use this view all over the place, and as a result, most of my queries seem very inefficient, having to do an Index Scan on TableA on almost every SELECT in my system.

What I'd like to know is whether there a way to store that MAX(Col3) so that it is computed during INSERTs and UPDATEs instead of during SELECTs?

Here are some thoughts and why I rejected them:

1. I don't think I can use a clustered indexed on the view, because "MAX(Col3)" is not deterministic.
2. I don't see how I can use a filtered view.
3. I don't want to use triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an index `tableA(col1, col2, col3)`.

Depending on the size of the table and the number of matches on `col1`, this should be quite reasonable performancewise.

Otherwise, you might need a summary table that is maintained using triggers.